# Moved old switch, now a different switch is flipping breaker

Tags: switch, circuit-breaker

We have three switches to our floodlights.
One switch is in a panel with three other switches. Those three In the were moved recently, including the floodlights switch.
Now, since the move, a different switch to the floodlights trips the breaker. The other two, including the one we moved, do not trip the breaker.

Comment: We're going to need a diagram  of how it was and how it is.

Comment: Thank you Jack! I’m very novice and my partner will know more: can you tell me what needs to be included in the diagram? Do you mean the wires for the moved switch?

Comment: The wires from the breaker to the switches to the flood lights and how they're hooked up to everything.... We, right now, have absolutely no idea what you did wrong.

Comment: Ok let me see what I can do

Comment: Are these all in the same box ? 2 ,3 , 4 wires to the switch?

Comment: In the meantime between a diagram or just a professional electrician: is it possible something is going to cause a fire, or are we safe if we don’t flip that switch until we get help?

Comment: Ed: the three switches that were moved are all in the same box. 
The switch we didn’t move but is now tripping the breaker is in a box with four other switches.

Comment: Ed, thanks! I forgot to add: the floodlights switch the we moved has 4 wires.

Comment: I recently solved a problem like that on a switched outlet.  Turning on the wall switch tripped the breaker.   Turned out that a bare ground wire in an outlet somehow, over time ended up touching the hot side screw of the outlet.   Perhaps moving stuff around you have a true short someplace. Actually you do have a true short or the breaker wouldn't trip.  Double check the work everywhere for a short, look for evidence of arcing.   True shorts are dangerous, don't experiment.  Like JACK says, providing a wiring diagram will help if it's not an obvious problem.

Comment: @GoVols In my non-professional opinion, I would leave the breaker turned off unless I really needed the lights. ("Floodlights" suggests to me that they are non-essential outdoor lights)